# Add lines in every /public_html/.htaccess file

Tags: centos, ssh, htaccess

Is there a way to perform an .htaccess edit in bulk through ssh?

I have multiple websites which goes like this:

```
/home/user/website1/public_html/.htaccess
/home/user/website2/public_html/.htaccess
...
```

And would like to add (not just replace the whole .htaccess ) at bottom of the file couple new lines, such as:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Another option, using a shell script, would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
for htaccess in home/user/website*/public_html/.htaccess
do
  cat >> "$htaccess" << 'EOF'
<FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
EOF
done
```

The script loops over every directory under /home/user that starts with "website" and appends the desired lines to the public_html/.htaccess file. I use a [*quoted* here-document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents) so that none of the contents are "helpfully" interpreted by the shell.

If you want to have a blank line separating the previous contents from the additions, simply insert it before the `<Filesmatch` portion that you're inserting (immediately after the `cat` line).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You only need to write some codes and run it on the server after ssh. For example, in Python:

```
# The lines you want to append
lines="""
<FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
"""

# The files need to append
files=[]
files.append('/home/user/website1/public_html/.htaccess')
files.append('/home/user/website2/public_html/.htaccess')

# Append lines to files
for file in files:
    f=open(file,'ab')
    f.write(lines)
    f.close()
```